# Как сократить код, убрав and?

Tags: python, оптимизация

```
a = 0
i = 1
while i == 1:
    a = a + 1
    if a % 1==0 and a % 2==0 and a % 3==0 and a % 5==0 and a % 6==0 and a % 7==0 and \
       a % 8==0 and a % 9==0 and a % 10==0 and a % 11==0 and a % 12==0 and \
       a % 13==0 and a % 14==0 and a % 15==0 and a % 16==0 and a % 17==0 and \
       a % 18==0 and a % 19==0 and a % 20==0:
           print(a)
           i=i + 1
    else:
        pass
```

Как сократить код, убрав `and`?

Comment: Это поиск НОК первых 20 чисел?

Comment: Нет никакого смысла, проверив `a % 16 == 0` проверять еще и остаток от деления на 2, 4 и 8. А проверяя делимость на 3 и 5, нет смысла дополнительно проверять делимость на 15.

Answer (score 19):

Попробуйте так:

```
if all(a%i == 0 for i in range(1, 21)):
    ...
```

Comment: ради true питонизма делать 4 миллиарда операций вместо четырёх десятков?

Comment: @MBo, вы [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/976410/211923) имеете в виду? ;)

Answer (score 9):

```
if all(a%num == 0 for num in numbers)
```

где `numbers` - список с вашими числами.

Единицу, кстати, можно выбросить - остаток любого числа от деления на единицу равен нулю. Да и двойку тоже. И еще несколько чисел.

Comment: практически одновременно :)

Comment: @MaxU ага :)   ..

Comment: Опечатка `if all(a % num == 0 for num in numbers)`?

Comment: @gil9red Точно, спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Более эффективное решение нахождения [наименьшего общего кратного (НОК)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) для списка чисел:

```
from functools import reduce

def gcd(a, b):
    while(b):
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    return abs(a * b) // gcd(a, b)

res = reduce(lcm, range(2, 21))
print(res)
# 232792560
```

Comment: Заинтересовало, пока не пользовался reduce(), возьму на заметку.